# Why is my checkbox styling not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I made some custom checkboxes and radio buttons. I styled them as follows with CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"] + label:after,
input[type="radio"][checked="checked"] + label:after,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 4px;
    left: -19px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #b7b7b7;
    content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"][checked="checked"] + label:after {
    background: none;
    top: 1px;
    left: -20px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    content: "\f00c";
}
```

The html of these elements looks like this

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="group in groups.initData.groups" 
     ng-checked="groups.modalData.access_groups[$index+1]">
    <input type="checkbox"
           class="group-checkbox">
    <label><% group.group %> </label>
</div>
```

Then i initialize them like this with JQuery when my angular view loads:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('input').prop("disabled"))
        return;

    if ($(this).children('input').prop("checked"))
        $(this).children('input').prop("checked", false);
    else
        $(this).children('input').prop("checked", true);

    $(this).children('input').change();
});


/* Radio handler */

$('.radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('input').prop("disabled"))
        return;

    var name = $(this).children('input').attr("name");

    $(this).children('input[name="' + name + '"]').prop("checked", false);

    $(this).children('input').prop("checked", true);

    $(this).children('input').change();

});
```

I don't understand why the styling doesn't apply? My angular code works and it correctly puts the checked="checked" attribute on the elements that are true for my expression

Comment: could you put it into [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) ?

Comment: The styles for the checked and unchecked are the same? Also checkboxes have limits to their styling, and even the ones that work aren't same across browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? As i can test it, it works as expected. I guess what you are missing is e.g: `.checkbox {
    position: relative;
}`

Comment: Sorry, ommited some css. I made an edit. I use the fornt awesome icon as you can see in the label when the checkbox is checked. Problem is my icon doesn't show up according to these selectors

Comment: Are you sure that's not just because it appears out of screen? Are you setting relevant position property for `.checkbox` div? By default it is static, you should set it to `relative` regarding `:after` pseudo element getting absolutely positioned. See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/q727eLy0/  FYI, don't use `[checked="checked"]`, checked is a boolean attribute, browser parser could just set it with empty/missing value

Comment: Yes, i am sure it doesn't appear offscreen. The problem it the attribute selector checked doesn't work. So it doesn't initialize. It still works if i click it but the selector is not working for that attribute and i need it to

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
```

is the problem here . Though you can style checkboxes ,there are some limitations. Like, if you are using some custom font-family , It wont work . Remove the font family and use following unicode content, and It should work.

```
content: "\2714";
```